# Golang reflect.SelectSend does not work and get false

Tags: go, reflection, select-case

I'm trying to use `reflect.Select` to send data in a channel. The code is as following.

```
c := make(chan int, 1)
vc := reflect.ValueOf(c)
go func() {
    <-c
}()
vSend := reflect.ValueOf(789)
branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
    {Dir: reflect.SelectSend, Chan: vc, Send: vSend},
}
selIndex, _, sentBeforeClosed := reflect.Select(branches)
fmt.Println(selIndex)
fmt.Println(sentBeforeClosed)
```

But I found it doesn't work, the result is

```
0 
false
```

why do I get `false`? How could I monitor a list of channels which could recv data?

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully read [`reflect.Select`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Select) documentation, you'll see that the third return value is relevant only when the direction of the `case` is a receive operation.

> Select executes a select operation described by the list of cases. Like the Go select statement, it blocks until at least one of the cases can proceed, makes a uniform pseudo-random choice, and then executes that case. It returns the index of the chosen case and, **if that case was a receive operation, the value received and a boolean indicating whether the value corresponds to a send on the channel** (as opposed to a zero value received because the channel is closed). [...]

In other words, the above means that *on receive operations* the third return value will be `true` if the channel received an actual value, or `false` if it received the zero value for the channel item type due to the channel being closed.

But your code uses `Dir: reflect.SelectSend`. On send operations, it is not necessary to inspect the boolean value because the send case will either be selected or not. If it is, the first return value `selIndex` will be the index of the selected case, and that's all you need to know. The third return value in this case is `false` simply because it is the zero value of the `bool` type.

If you change your code to use `Dir: reflect.SelectRecv`, then the boolean value will have meaning, based on the above quoted documentation:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 1)
    vc := reflect.ValueOf(c)
    go func() {
        c <- 789
    }()
    branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: vc},
    }
    selIndex, recVal, recOK := reflect.Select(branches)
    fmt.Println(selIndex, recVal, recOK)

    selIndex, recVal, recOK = reflect.Select(branches)
    fmt.Println(selIndex, recVal, recOK)
}
```

Prints:

```
0 789 true
0 0 false
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ezuc_OaK_SW